# CSS: Nested element height when parent dimensions are set with pixels

Tags: html, css, layout

Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbDJu/3/).

This is a very dumbed-down version of a more complex form. In `.dojoxAlertBar`, the height is set to 100% for programming reasons. Things are all good, until I set the height for `#registerform` as a set number:

```
/*    height:117px;  */
```

Without this, the height of the message is "as big as it needs to be". However, uncommenting the 117px height in the CSS has the result of making the height of `.dojoAlertBox` equal to `#registerForm`.

Can somebody please explain why that is? I keep on misunderstanding how "height" works in CSS. What does that "100%" actually mean? If it means "100% of the containing element", then why isn't it set as "big" even when there is no specified height for the parent?

In fact, if I can beg, having a simple table of how the height is calculated for fixed/absolute and relative/static elements, that would be great too.

Comment: You might want to use jsfiddle rather than pastebin since people can preview your site. [jsFiddle for this question](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/zuTLn/)

Comment: Done! And will do in the future :D

Comment: nice, tho you could have used mine! Oh and in jsFiddle you usually separate your code in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (not copying it all to the HTML haha).

Comment: Wooops... I didn't see yours, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WITHOUT this, the height of the message is "as big as it needs to be".

To give an element (`.dojoAlertBar`) a percentage height, its parent element (`#registerForm`) must have an explicit height. Since, in your example, `.registerForm` has a height of auto, the block will take the height of its content.

> However, UNCOMMENTING this has the result of making the comment box as big as the #registerForm...What does that "100%" actually mean?

A height of 100% means the element will have a height that is 100% of its parent. Therefore, the parent div must have an explicit height property. When you give `#registerForm` the height of 117px, that means `.dojoAlertBar` will be 100% of that height, or 117px.

Comment: "To give an element a percentage height, its parent element  must have an explicit height." <-- So, the "100%" won't apply to _calculated_ heights, but only to the ones explicitly declared in the CSS...? Really?

Comment: @Merc. Exactly. Unless the parent has a height specified in the CSS, it is `auto` by default. That height does not necessarily have to be a pixel count -- it can also be a percentage if you want, but that just moves the problem up to the next level.

Comment: Plus, I can programmatically change that size from 0% to 100% (and I do, to give it a nice effect) and it works. Since I sort of _have to_ have a percentile size, but I also want the message to be "as big as it needs to be", is there a better way to do that in terms of HTML?

Comment: I guess my real question then is: How do I structure that HTML so that 1) I can set size to % in .dojoAlertBar 2) The message is as big as it needs to be without hogging the whole form 3) The form itself has a predetermined size ...? I wonder if this is even possible...?!?

Comment: @Merc. What purpose does it serve to have a percentage height on `.dojoAlertBox`? If you are not actually controlling the height with that feature, why not just omit it?

Comment: I use it so that I can programmatically make it shrink/reappear when the message pops up. So, I guess I am -- at the moment, I am controlling its height by going from 0% to 100% and then back...

Comment: @Merc. The simplest solution I can think of is making its height go from 0% to auto and then back, for the same effect. Would that work in your program? Or if the message is always the same, you could work out a specific pixel height that would fit the message and use that instead of auto